# No definition and no extension method of assembly method missing?

Tags: c#, winforms

It's a common error and normally I'm able to solve it.

I have a class:

**HierarchyData.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CT_WMT.App_Code
{
    public class HierarchyData
    {
        string sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SnaggingMasterConnection"].ConnectionString;

        public DataTable GetHierarchyData()
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_GetHierachy", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                try
                {
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string errorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
                }

                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my calling webform:

[image: Screenshot]

I think I'm just missing it and it's right in front of my eyes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system cannot distinguish between HierarchyData the Page (full name `CT_WMT.Secure.HierarchyData.HierarchyData`) and HierarchyData the Data Loading class (full name `CT_WMT.App_Code.HierarchyData`).

You can:

1. Use the full name:

   ```
   CT_WMT.App_Code.HierarchyData myClass = new CT_WMT.App_Code.HierarchyData();
   DataTable dt = myClass.GetHierarchyData();
   ```
2. Declare an alias for HierarchyData the Data Loading class

   ```
   using HierarchyDataLoader = CT_WMT.App_Code.HierarchyData; 
   ...
   HierarchyDataLoader myClass = new HierarchyDataLoader();
   DataTable dt = myClass.GetHierarchyData();
   ```
3. Rename one or both of them so each class has a unique name, e.g. add `Page` suffix to the page, or `Loader` suffix to the loader class.

Comment: I've accepted your comment as the answer as you were the first to suggest changing the names. I also think there was an underlying problem as I copied the project into a new website in Visual Studio and it ran. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer the `HierarchyData` with fully qualified `namespace`:

Try This:

```
CT_WMT.App_Code.HierarchyData myClass = new CT_WMT.App_Code.HierarchyData();
DataTable dt = myClass.GetHierarchy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two partial classes are in different namespaces, making them different types.  They need to be in the same namespace to be partial definitions of the same type.  They also *both* need to have the `partial` keyword.

You should also evaluate whether you really want these types to be partial definitions of the same class; consider simply having two different types in which an entirely separate type is responsible for this database query.

You should also avoid catching exceptions and doing nothing with them.  If you don't have any meaningful way of handling an error, don't try to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, HierarchyData is referring to your ASP.NET Page (`CT_WMT.Secure.HierarchyData`), which has the same name as the class in your App_Code (`CT_WMT.App_Code.HierarchyData`).

Not sure if you intend the one in App_Code to be a partial class and thus part of the ASP.NET page or not. If you do, you need to set it as partial and make it part of the same namespace. Regardless, you need to sort of the class name/namespace issues.

Comment: It tells him what the problem is. He said he was pretty sure it was right in front of his eyes (it was). So I pointed it out. That said, I added more information.

Comment: Having two types with the same name isn't a problem.  Having classes that *ought* to be partial definitions of the same class, that aren't bound together, is.

Comment: There's no guarantee he wanted them to be partials. One could have been intended to be a helper class. In which case the issue was that he needed to reference the class by the FQN. Thus I pointed out what the problem was - that they had the same name and thus he was confused. He has to tell us what his intentions were in order to know actually how to fix it.